# "Variables must be final" compiler errors attempting to use Java 8 streams API

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to do the leetcode - Given an array of integers every element appears three times except one, which appears exactly once. I am trying to use streams to do it so that I can practice Java 8. But I keep getting different errors. I would like to use findFirst() as once I find the element I don't need to keep iterating over the HashMap.

```
   public class Solution {
    public int singleNumber(int[] nums) {

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int num: nums){
            if (map.containsValue(num))
            map.put(num, map.get(num) +1);
            else
            map.put(num, 1);
        }

       map.forEach((k, v) -> {

           if (v == 1)
               return k;
       });

    }
}
```

When I run the above I get

```
Line 13: error: no suitable method found for forEach((k,v)->{ i[...] k; })
```

When I try

```
    public class Solution {
    public int singleNumber(int[] nums) {

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int num: nums){
            if (map.containsValue(num))
                map.put(num, map.get(num) +1);
            else
                map.put(num, 1);
        }

        Map<Integer, Integer> answer= map.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getValue() == 1)
                .findFirst()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));
        return answer.getValue();
    }
}
```

I get `cannot resolve method collect`. If I remove the collect line, then it complains about needing a semicolon.

When I try

```
 int number = 0;
   map.forEach((k, v) -> {

       if (v == 1)
           number = k;
   });
  return number;
```

I get `Line 16: error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final`
Expected answer

But if I declare number to be final then it says I can't assign it.

When I try (as the last line in the stream)

> .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i));

I get

> Line 15: error: cannot find symbol: method collect(Collector>>)

If I remove the last line of the stream and change the next to last line to

> .findFirst());

Then I get

> Line 14: error: ';' expected this is for two or three ).

If I do

> .findFirst();

Then I get

> Line 14: error: incompatible types: Optional>
>   cannot be converted to Map

Comment: "keep getting different errors"... what errors? be specific? post exactly the code that is failing and tell us what error is happening. until you have that, the question is off topic

Comment: There is no collect() method on an Entry. You're iterating over and Set of Entry's (EntrySet)

Comment: If I remove the collect() then I get Optional cannot be converted to Map.Line 14: error: incompatible types: Optional<Entry<Integer,Integer>> cannot be converted to Map<Integer,Integer>
Expected answer

Comment: You need to start reading, and making sense of error messages. findFirst(), as very clearly written in the javadoc, return an instance of Optional. You're trying to assign this Optional to a variable of type Map. An Optional is not a Map. So your code makes no sense, and that's what the compiler tells you. Don't try random things. Read the javadoc, and read error messages.

Comment: I'm not trying random things. I was basing my answer on tutorials. I also read the docs but didn't understand them.

Comment: quick note, instead of your if, else part, have a look at [map.merge()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) it might make your code a little tidier

Comment: You *are* trying random things. Once you learned that `findFirst` returns an `Optional`, you should go straight to the documentation of `Optional` to find out, how to check for the presence of a value and how to extract it. It’s easy. There is no reason to try appending a `collect` that would return a `Map`, if that ever worked. And what’s `getValue()`?! there is no such method in `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` doesn't expect a return type, it's a "consuming" function hence your error.

To answer your question about "local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final" in Java you cannot assign a value to the variable named `number` again from within a Lambda (or indeed outside of the lambda either). It's a limitation of the way Lambda's have been implemented. As the message says it has to be marked as a `final` or you never assign another value to `number` after it has been initialised (effectively final).

As a starting point for an alternative solution, try using `groupingBy`

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = Stream.of(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i));
```

Gives you the following

```
{1=[1, 1, 1], 2=[2], 3=[3, 3, 3]}
```

**Edit**

Instead of looping with forEach, we can use another stream to return your single `int` you want (i.e. `2`).

Given the map output above you want to filter and keep just the entry in the map that have only one value, so do this next

```
List<List<Integer>> onlyOne = map.values().stream()
    .filter(v -> v.size() == 1)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Gives you the following single entry

```
[[2]]
```

Now all you have to do is extract the value `2`

*Disclaimer: there are many ways to solve this problem with streams, I'm trying to help you think functionally with this example rather than give you a one line solution that you may not understand*

Comment: I changed the last name in the stream to groupingBy and got this error 
Your answer

Line 15: error: cannot find symbol: method collect(Collector<Object,CAP#1,Map<Object,List<Object>>>) Also I can't declare that number variable in the lambda expression and then return that either. There is only one int that I need to return not a list of hashmap.

Comment: Hi @Sam take a look at my edit, and reply back if you have any more questions